# JQuery Datatables Highlight Row After Initialisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I have a table with several columns of data that uses jQuery's data table's library.

One of these columns is an expiration date. I want to highlight the columns where the expiration date has been passed so an administrator can pick out visually which need to be updated without actually reading each date.

Here is what my table looks like:

[image]
End date is the column that should be checked. The problem is since I use jquery's generator method I do not want to modify it to check for past dates because I use the same method on several other pages.

My question is, **Is there any way to loop through the table after the page has loaded and modify the CSS to highlight the row when the end date column has passed (and have it work for every page of the data table, not just the current page)?**

Can anybody point me in the right direction? I don't know if there is a built in function for what I want or if I am going to have to make a little hack, but I thought I'd check here first.

Comment: Can you please show your DataTables initialization code in JavaScript? Are you using client-side or server-side processing?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using datatables 1.9 you can use [fnRowCallback](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnRowCallback) for this:

In this example, the callback method runs after each row is processed (but not rendered yet), and we're checking to see if the value in column 5 equals 'A', and if true, then the class `hilite` is applied to each `<td>` within that row.

```
"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
    if(aData[4] == 'A'){
        $(nRow).children().each(function (index, td) {
              $(this).addClass('hilite');
        });   
    }
    return nRow;
}
```

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/HEDvf/3069/) for a working example